# $_SESSION Not displaying (Noob)

Tags: php, database, session

I've set up a login/registration system from a tutorial, Now i am trying to use sessions to display profile information. I've looked at quite a few forums and tutorials and i believe i have the actual code needed to display the actual information from the database, But i can not get it to show. I am probably doing something wrong... I'm trying to get the "Email" part from the database and display it for the profile.

```
<?php
require('db.php');

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("XXXXXX");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, username, email FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];


?>  
<?php
session_start();
?>
<p><strong>Email:</strong>&nbsp;<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?></p>
```

Comment: you need to put session_start() on the very top of your php file

Comment: Why session_start at last? It should be before $_SESSION

Comment: simple: start the session FIRST not after and make sure the POST array has value; no idea where/how that is coming from.

Comment: you've been given comments; please don't ignore them or expect a magic answer for what you posted, since the POST array is unknown. Good luck.

Comment: I have posted the session_start() at the top, Thankyou. But it still displays nothing.. I believe that the session is created somewhere else when i was following the tutorial for the login it creates a session, is it possible to create separate instances of this? as it doesn't seem to be working still

Comment: I'm going to read more into the POST array, Thankyou for your comments. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

From the limited info i can think of this :

- You have already completed login/registration module
- Once user is successfully logged in, you want to display profile info for that user, Right?

In this case here is basic assumption of your situation :

1. First of all if you are transferring your user to this page after login, it means there will be no $_POST data (Generally). you can confirm it using var_dump($_POST).
2. You already have $_SESSION variable setup somewhere at the time of login. let's assume it is $_SESSION['email'], you can confirm it using var_dump($_SESSION).

Based on this assumption, this is how your modified code will look like :

```
<?php
require('db.php');

//This should come first before accessing $_SESSION
session_start();

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("XXXXXX");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//This query should be used with WHERE as you only want to get data of one particular user. 
//This is just for an example purpose, in practice you should always use parameterized query Or at least escape data before using it. 
$sql = "SELECT id, username, email FROM users WHERE email = " . $_SESSION['email'] . ";";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       //Assuming only one record will be returned because username/email should be unique
       $result = $row;
    }
} else {
    //Handle if you don't get any data
}

$email = $result['email']; 

?>  

<p><strong>Email:</strong>&nbsp;<?php echo $email; ?></p>
```

I hope this might be of some help